# id token is invalid for this user react native google sign in

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using google sign in on android in a react native app.  I have setup the web, and android clientId with sha1 correctly.
I get the idToken back, have checked the expiration, it is not expired, everything appears to be valid, but...